# How to fix Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable?

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I have a form built with Smarty. After I submit my form, I get this message, I am running PHP 7.2. I understand this is a common problem.

Here is the line of code in my form validation that is giving me the error:

```
if(!count( $_SESSION['err'] ) > 0 )
```

I had a similar problem in my form HTML, the solution to that was chage:

```
<?php if count($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['Transaction']->value) > 0)
```

to:

```
<?php if (is_array($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['Transaction']->value) && count($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['Transaction']->value) > 0)
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION['err']);` give you?

Comment: You did it correctly in your second example. Simply, for PHP 7 you have to check if variable is an array or object in case of counting. You would also get an error if you tried to access `$_SESSION['err']`, cause it was not set.

Comment: So just add `if(is_array($_SESSION['err']) && !count( $_SESSION['err'] ) > 0 )` ?